# Cleaning up python's on OS X Yosemite

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-yosemite

There appears to be a bit of a mess on my (migrated up from 10.8.5) Yosemite machine. I used to run python 2.7 and that worked well. I'm not sure where I installed that one from, could have have been macports, or brew. Now when I run python -V I get 2.5 (yikes!) which is the one located in /usr/local/bin/python and is based on the /Library frameork, that's prehistoric, no idea how that even got there. The following other versions are installed on the system:

```
ll /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 29 Jun 11:29 2.3 -> 2.6
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 29 Jun 11:29 2.5 -> 2.6
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 29 Jun 11:29 2.6
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 29 Jun 11:29 2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    3 29 Jun 11:29 Current -> 2.7
```

and, to confuse things:

```
ll /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin  340 26 Apr  2010 2.5
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  admin  340 31 Dec  2012 3.3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   49 31 Dec  2012 Current -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3
```

So how can I clean this up? Why are there 4 python versions in 2 different paths on my system? How can I make OS X use 2.7?

Comment: @Padraic: No, don’t do that! `/usr/bin/python` is only a stub which locates and then invokes the *real* Python interpreter. If you delete everything else, you won’t have a Python installation at all any more!

Comment: @icktoofay, I meant all bar the system python

Comment: @Padraic: Oh, okay. That would work.

Comment: but which one is the "system python"?

Comment: 2.7, the one that came installed with the OS `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: So /Library/Frameworks/Python.* can be rm -rf'd? I wonder what put that there.

Comment: keep the 2.7 and remove the others, also add the output from `which -a python`